# Telegram Bot не получается начать диалог первым

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Telegram Bot API Changelog

```
December 7, 2021

Bot API 5.5

   Bots are now allowed to contact users who sent a join request to a chat where the bot is an administrator with the can_invite_users administrator right – even if the user never interacted with the bot before.
```

Еще в прошлом году добавили функцию, когда пользователь отправляет запрос подписки на канал, то бот может начать с ним диалог первым. Это точно работает, потому что это я увидел сегодня в другом канале. Я просто подал заявку и мне через пол секунды написал бот из этого канала и отправил какую-то рекламу.

Так вот пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


@bot.chat_join_request_handler()
def test(message):
    
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.approve_chat_join_request(message.chat.id, user_id) # принимаю запрос
    bot.send_message(user_id, 'test message')
```

И вижу ошибку:

```
Forbidden: bot can't initiate conversation with a user
```

Так как мне это сделать? Пытался нагуглить и в других библиотеках, помимо pyTelegramBotAPI, но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, если вдруг кому поможет. Не получалось сделать это из-за того, что к каналу уже ранее был подключен другой бот, поэтому когда попытался подключить второго - телега этого сделать не давала

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то таким образом удалось отправить "личное" сообщение пользователю в отдельном чате или как? Я получаю ошибку, что не указан `chat_id` в таком варианте (использую голый запрос, без обёрток).